# Jenkins Installation Wizard Error

Tags: linux, jenkins, amazon-ec2, digital-ocean

I've tried installing Jenkins on AWS & DigitalOcean instances/droplets without any luck.

For EC2 instances used the latest Amazon Linux AMI (ami-f9dd458a) & Ubuntu 14.04 (ami-ed82e39e). On DigitalOcean I tried using Ubuntu 14.04 & 16.04. I've also attempted to install jenkins using jdk-7 & jdk-8 following [Debian based installation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu) or [Red-Hat distribution installation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Red+Hat+distributions) instructions (even tried to install LTS version).

For all of the above the installation runs smoothly but after unlocking with the `initialAdminPassword` and selecting either option in the wizard ("Install suggested plugins" or "Select plugins to install") I face a connection (?) error:

[image]

I copied the logs from `/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log` and they are [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/fdoxyz/43c038cae7a863995081cbc175fb8ec1).

Could this be a dumb mistake I did along the way? I've used Jenkins from a docker container but kinda need to install natively now for. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: Install on an instance with more RAM.

For some reason I had no problems installing in a smaller machine using the docker image. Oh well :)