# Installing Jenkins on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I am running into an issue with the install wizard with Jenkins when following a [Set Up a Jenkins Build Server](https://d0.awsstatic.com/Projects/P5505030/aws-project_Jenkins-build-server.pdf) tutorial from Amazon.

My EC2 instance is a t2.small. It was a t2.micro until I saw this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39179886/jenkins-installation-wizard-error) so I switched it to a t2.small. It doesn't appear to be a memory issue. I am getting an error when creating my initial user or trying to `Continue as admin`.

When inspecting the element, trying to `Save and Finish` when creating an initial user, `POST http://<domain>:8080/setupWizard/createAdminUser` errors out with a `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` error. (I don't see anything in `/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log` about this failure either)

[image: Error message seen here]

I am running java 1.8 and I've tried with Jenkins 2.71-1.1 and Jenkins 2.61-1.1

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

I grepped the error log and only found one log pertaining to errors (but I'm not sure this is related):

```
Jul 24, 2017 11:09:50 PM hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder$FaultTolerantScope$1 error
INFO: Failed to instantiate optional component hudson.plugins.build_timeout.operations.AbortAndRestartOperation$DescriptorImpl; skipping
```

Comment: The `jenkins.log` looks completely unsuspicious?

Comment: there was one, I added it to the post body

Comment: If you're dead set on hosting your own jenkins, use the official docker image... its a much better experience especially when using VM's (ie: cloud instance) .. I've been using jenkins VIA docker in my home lab for years and scaling up workers in easy as pie and you only worry about the data, especially when you'll be running secuirty updates every other day ... just pull the latest image and restart

Answer (score 0):

I created a CDK to provision a Jenkins service in AWS. have a try

https://github.com/seraphjiang/jenkinscdk

Answer (score 0):

Install the certificates-

```
sudo apt install ca-certificates
```

then, Try Updating & Upgrading the packages-

```
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt update
```

Then follow the link to install the Jenkins :)

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-jenkins-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).